# When I runned windows bat to rename a set of files by adding prefix which is longer than 2 chars,why the first file will be renamed twice?

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

> @echo off
>   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>   echo,&set/p x=Step1.Please input type of files(type * for all files)
>   echo,&set/p sign=Step2.Please input prefix
>   for %%i in (*.%x%) do (
>   set "filename=%%i"
>   if defined sign set "filename=%sign%!filename!"
>   if not "%%i"=="!filename!" ren "%%i" "!filename!"
>   )
>   echo,Works done!press any key to quit...
>   pause>nul

Comment: Please, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19705611/2861476)

Comment: @MCND thanks, but... is there any way to solve this problem?Though I used `(??.%x%)` to void it in my case.

Comment: See answer. Not more detailed than the original link, but maybe one solution to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the list of files retrieved by the `for` command is dynamic. If initially there is more than one file matching the set, then the list will be rereaded (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705611/2861476)) and if the first processed file is renamed to anything that also matches the set in `for` command, it will be reprocessed.

One solution is to first retrieve the full list and then process it. It can be done with `for /f` and `dir` commands

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "*.%x%"') do ( ....
```

`for /f` will always retrieve all the information to process before starting to process it. So, the dir command is executed once and then its output processed.

Other solution (as indicated in comments by OP) is to ensure the indicated set of files in `for` command will not match the new renamed files.