# How to insert a text in front of the filenames using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

```
@echo off 
for %%a in (*.xhtml) do (

ren "%%~fa" "epub_%%~nxa"
)
```

I am using the code for insert a text ("epub_") to all the file names.

The file name is

```
00_Cover_Page.xhtml
01_Halftitle.xhtml
02_Title.xhtml
03_Copyright.xhtml
04_Dedication.xhtml
05_Preface.xhtml
06_Contents.xhtml
```

It's renaming good except "**`00_Cover_Page.xhtml`**"

**`epub_epub_00_Cover_Page.xhtml`** ("epub_" Inserted twice in the filename only)

```
epub_01_Halftitle.xhtml
epub_02_Title.xhtml
epub_03_Copyright.xhtml
epub_04_Dedication.xhtml
epub_05_Preface.xhtml
epub_06_Contents.xhtml
```

How could it be happened?

Comment: The *"How"* can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19705611/2861476)

Comment: @MCND - That is your "Why is it failing" answer. jeb's answer to the same question explains how to fix it.

Comment: @dbenham, yes, the jeb's answer to the same linked question gives a solution, and the user1016274's solution here gives another, but I was not answering the question in the title (substring insert), just included a comment because the final line in the OP's question is *"How could it be happened?"*. Next time i will be more precise. Thank you

Comment: @MCND - Ah - I didn't read carefully, and interpreted that last line as another file name, without actually reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in MC ND's comment, an explanation of the behavior is available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705611/1012053. The FOR loop buffers only a portion of the directory, and when it goes back to disk to read additional file entries, it can pick up already renamed files.

[jeb's answer on that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705294/1012053) explains how to avoid the problem by using a FOR /F loop processing a DIR /B command - the output of the DIR /B command is captured in its entirety before iterations begin.

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.xhtml') do ren "%%F" "epub_%%~nxa"
```

An alternative is to use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081). JREN.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren "^" "epub_" /fm *.xhtml
```

Use CALL JREN if you put the command within a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the `FOR` loop picks up the already renamed files. You can avoid this in (at least) 2 ways:

1. Filter on the orignal filenames if possible:

   `for %A in (0*.xhtml) do @ren "%~nxA" "epub_%~nxA"`
2. Create a filename list beforehand and use it in the loop:

   `set tmpfile=files%RANDOM%.tmp`
   `dir /b *.xhtml > %tmpfile%`
   `for /f %A in (%tmpfile%) do @ren "%~nxA" "epub_%~nxA"`
   `del %tmpfile%`
   `set tmpfile=`